# Meaning of nat in boost c++ library source

Tags: c++, variables, boost

In certain portions of boost c++ libraries you read things like:

```
template<>
struct add_reference<void>
{
  typedef const nat &type;
};
```

OR

```
struct nat {int for_bool;};
```

Is nat a acronym (Not a Type)? If not what is its significance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw this nat in type_traits.hpp and it seems that it's Not a Type; in fact, it acts like a specialization of `template<class T> struct add_reference<T&>` for the `void` case; it seems to represent a reference to void and it's probably there for completeness of the implementation.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'd consider filing an enhancement request that the idea be documented.